# Why java faker generating sentence in Latin language. I need in English language

Tags: java, sentence, lorem-ipsum

Here is my code.

```
Faker faker = new Faker(new Locale("en-GB"));
String title = faker.lorem().sentence(3);
System.out.println("title = " + title);
```

The output is as below.

```
title = Ut at quis corrupti explicabo.
```

I checked in google translate. It is in the Latin language. How can I get the sentence in the English language?

Comment: Where is the Faker class from? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum also Java Faker is not a translator.

Comment: Please read the tag description of the tags you're using. Neither the faker nor the lorem-ipsum tags are related to your question.

Comment: The Faker class provides dozens of methods that generate all kinds of things. If you don't want the lorem ipsum text then don't use the lorem method. Pick something else.

Comment: Faker class is in maven dependency, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker

Comment: @GulammustufaMomin What kind of text do you want to generate? There are [other faker categories](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker#fakers) than "Lorem" in the library you can use.

Comment: But frankly .... why do your even care what language the text is in?  It is ... by design ... nonsensical text.  Nonsense in one language is as good as nonsense in another.

Comment: `Locale` is not used for `Lorem`, but for postcodes, counties, phone numbers, some number formats and similar. (see the [en-GB.yml](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/blob/master/src/main/resources/en-GB.yml) file). Reason: see previous comment - it is not expected for it to return any real word

Comment: Yes, I got it. Locale is not used for Lorem.

Answer (score 0):

To translate Latin (or any other language) to English you would obviously need a translator as **[Java-Faker](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.javafaker/javafaker/latest/com/github/javafaker/Faker.html)** doesn't do this. The easiest (I should think) would be to snag the translation from the internet.

I had the following method in my archives but I have no idea who wrote it. It does work but utilizes the *WhatsApp*'s **WhatsMate WA Gateway** so, internet access is a requirement. I'm not really sure this is necessarily a good thing or not but here is a runnable demo in any case:

```
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class FakerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FakerDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        Faker faker = new Faker(); 
        String title = faker.lorem().sentence(3);
        try {
            System.out.println("Title: -> " + translate(title, "Latin", "English"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Sends out a WhatsApp message via WhatsMate WA Gateway. Can translate any
     * language to any other language. Below is a list of 91 Languages and their
     * respective abbreviation that this method can Translate to and from:
     * <pre>
     *
     * Abbreviation, Language Name
     *  <table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
     *      <tr><td>af, Afrikaans</td><td>gl, Galician</td><td>lt, Lithuanian</td><td>so, Somali</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>ar, Arabic</td><td>gu, Gujarati</td><td>lv, Latvian</td><td>sq, Albanian</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>az, Azerbaijani</td><td>ha, Hausa</td><td>ma, Punjabi</td><td>sr, Serbian</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>be, Belarusian</td><td>hi, Hindi</td><td>mg, Malagasy</td><td>st, Sesotho</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>bg, Bulgarian</td><td>hmn, Hmong</td><td>mi, Maori</td><td>su, Sudanese</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>bn, Bengali</td><td>hr, Croatian</td><td>mk, Macedonian</td><td>sv, Swedish</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>bs, Bosnian</td><td>ht, Haitian Creole</td><td>ml, Malayalam</td><td>sw, Swahili</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>ca, Catalan</td><td>hu, Hungarian</td><td>mn, Mongolian</td><td>ta, Tamil</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>ceb, Cebuano</td><td>hy, Armenian</td><td>mr, Marathi</td><td>te, Telugu</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>cs, Czech</td><td>id, Indonesian</td><td>ms, Malay</td><td>tg, Tajik</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>cy, Welsh</td><td>ig, Igbo</td><td>mt, Maltese</td><td>th, Thai</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>da, Danish</td><td>is, Icelandic</td><td>my, Myanmar (Burmese)</td><td>tl, Filipino</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>de, German</td><td>it, Italian</td><td>ne, Nepali</td><td>tr, Turkish</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>el, Greek</td><td>iw, Hebrew</td><td>nl, Dutch</td><td>uk, Ukrainian</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>en, English</td><td>ja, Japanese</td><td>no, Norwegian</td><td>ur, Urdu</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>eo, Esperanto</td><td>jw, Javanese</td><td>ny, Chichewa</td><td>uz, Uzbek</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>es, Spanish</td><td>ka, Georgian</td><td>pl, Polish</td><td>vi, Vietnamese</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>et, Estonian</td><td>kk, Kazakh</td><td>pt, Portuguese</td><td>yi, Yiddish</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>eu, Basque</td><td>km, Khmer</td><td>ro, Romanian</td><td>yo, Yoruba</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>fa, Persian</td><td>kn, Kannada</td><td>ru, Russian</td><td>zcn, Chinese Simplified</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>fi, Finnish</td><td>ko, Korean</td><td>si, Sinhala</td><td>ztw, Chinese Traditional</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>fr, French</td><td>la, Latin</td><td>sk, Slovak</td><td>zu, Zulu</td></tr>
     *      <tr><td>ga, Irish</td><td>lo, Lao</td><td>sl, Slovenian</td><td></td></tr>
     *  </table>
     * </pre><br>
     * <p>
     * This method also ensures that an Internet connection exists. General
     * (simple) errors are returned as text string from this method.
     *
     * @param textToTranslate (String) The text to translate.<br>
     * 
     * @param fromLang (String) The language Name or Abbreviation (as describe
     *                 within the information above) to convert FROM.<br>
     *
     * @param toLang   (String) The language Name or Abbreviation (as describe
     *                 within the information above) to convert TO.<br>
     *
     * @return (String) The language translation.<br>
     *
     * @throws java.lang.Exception Should any issue arise.
     */
    public static String translate(String textToTranslate, String fromLang, String toLang) throws Exception {
        // Is there internet...
        // ---------------------------------------
        boolean hasInternet;
        /* Connect to Google DNS via port 53. Sometimes Anti-Virus
           applications will block standard internet access from 
           applications that do not contain a digital signature. This
           is one way to get around that problem...at least for checking
           to see if there is indeed internet access for the system.  */
        String host = "8.8.8.8";
        int port = 53;
        try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 5000);
            hasInternet = true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            hasInternet = false;
        }
        if (!hasInternet) {
            return "No Internet availalble to acquire translation!";
        }
        // ---------------------------------------

        // Language Map...
        HashMap<String, String> langMap = new HashMap<>();
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Language Map Data ">
        langMap.put("af", "Afrikaans");
        langMap.put("ar", "Arabic");
        langMap.put("az", "Azerbaijani");
        langMap.put("be", "Belarusian");
        langMap.put("bg", "Bulgarian");
        langMap.put("bn", "Bengali");
        langMap.put("bs", "Bosnian");
        langMap.put("ca", "Catalan");
        langMap.put("ceb", "Cebuano");
        langMap.put("cs", "Czech");
        langMap.put("cy", "Welsh");
        langMap.put("da", "Danish");
        langMap.put("de", "German");
        langMap.put("el", "Greek");
        langMap.put("en", "English");
        langMap.put("eo", "Esperanto");
        langMap.put("es", "Spanish");
        langMap.put("et", "Estonian");
        langMap.put("eu", "Basque");
        langMap.put("fa", "Persian");
        langMap.put("fi", "Finnish");
        langMap.put("fr", "French");
        langMap.put("ga", "Irish");
        langMap.put("gl", "Galician");
        langMap.put("gu", "Gujarati");
        langMap.put("ha", "Hausa");
        langMap.put("hi", "Hindi");
        langMap.put("hmn", "Hmong");
        langMap.put("hr", "Croatian");
        langMap.put("ht", "Haitian Creole");
        langMap.put("hu", "Hungarian");
        langMap.put("hy", "Armenian");
        langMap.put("id", "Indonesian");
        langMap.put("ig", "Igbo");
        langMap.put("is", "Icelandic");
        langMap.put("it", "Italian");
        langMap.put("iw", "Hebrew");
        langMap.put("ja", "Japanese");
        langMap.put("jw", "Javanese");
        langMap.put("ka", "Georgian");
        langMap.put("kk", "Kazakh");
        langMap.put("km", "Khmer");
        langMap.put("kn", "Kannada");
        langMap.put("ko", "Korean");
        langMap.put("la", "Latin");
        langMap.put("lo", "Lao");
        langMap.put("lt", "Lithuanian");
        langMap.put("lv", "Latvian");
        langMap.put("ma", "Punjabi");
        langMap.put("mg", "Malagasy");
        langMap.put("mi", "Maori");
        langMap.put("mk", "Macedonian");
        langMap.put("ml", "Malayalam");
        langMap.put("mn", "Mongolian");
        langMap.put("mr", "Marathi");
        langMap.put("ms", "Malay");
        langMap.put("mt", "Maltese");
        langMap.put("my", "Myanmar (Burmese)");
        langMap.put("ne", "Nepali");
        langMap.put("nl", "Dutch");
        langMap.put("no", "Norwegian");
        langMap.put("ny", "Chichewa");
        langMap.put("pl", "Polish");
        langMap.put("pt", "Portuguese");
        langMap.put("ro", "Romanian");
        langMap.put("ru", "Russian");
        langMap.put("si", "Sinhala");
        langMap.put("sk", "Slovak");
        langMap.put("sl", "Slovenian");
        langMap.put("so", "Somali");
        langMap.put("sq", "Albanian");
        langMap.put("sr", "Serbian");
        langMap.put("st", "Sesotho");
        langMap.put("su", "Sudanese");
        langMap.put("sv", "Swedish");
        langMap.put("sw", "Swahili");
        langMap.put("ta", "Tamil");
        langMap.put("te", "Telugu");
        langMap.put("tg", "Tajik");
        langMap.put("th", "Thai");
        langMap.put("tl", "Filipino");
        langMap.put("tr", "Turkish");
        langMap.put("uk", "Ukrainian");
        langMap.put("ur", "Urdu");
        langMap.put("uz", "Uzbek");
        langMap.put("vi", "Vietnamese");
        langMap.put("yi", "Yiddish");
        langMap.put("yo", "Yoruba");
        langMap.put("zcn", "Chinese Simplified");
        langMap.put("zct", "Chinese Traditional");
        langMap.put("zu", "Zulu");
        //</editor-fold>

        // Ensure supplied FROM/TO Language spec's are in lowercase.
        fromLang = fromLang.toLowerCase();
        toLang = toLang.toLowerCase();

        boolean foundLang = false;
        // If only the FROM language abrieviation (map key) is provided...
        // fromLang parameter...
        if (fromLang.length() < 4) {
            if (!langMap.containsKey(fromLang.toLowerCase())) {
                return "ERROR! Can not locate specified 'FROM' Language! --> (" + fromLang + ")";
            }
        }
        // If full FROM language Name (map value) is provided...
        else {
            String value = fromLang;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : langMap.entrySet()) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getValue())) {
                    fromLang = entry.getKey();
                    foundLang = true;
                    break; //breaking because its one to one map
                }
            }
            if (!foundLang) {
                return "ERROR! Can not locate specified 'FROM' Language! --> (" + fromLang + ")";
            }
        }
        // If only the TO language abrieviation (map key) is provided... 
        // toLang parameter...
        foundLang = false;
        if (toLang.length() < 4) {
            if (!langMap.containsKey(toLang)) {
                return "ERROR! Can not locate specified 'TO' Language! --> (" + toLang + ")";
            }
        }
        // If full TO language Name (map value) is provided...
        else {
            String value = toLang;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : langMap.entrySet()) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getValue())) {
                    toLang = entry.getKey();
                    foundLang = true;
                    break; //breaking because its one to one map
                }
            }
            if (!foundLang) {
                return "ERROR! Can not locate specified 'TO' Language! --> (" + toLang + ")";
            }
        }
        if (fromLang.equalsIgnoreCase("zcn")) {
            fromLang = "zh-CN";
        }
        else if (fromLang.equalsIgnoreCase("zct")) {
            fromLang = "zh-CT";
        }
        if (toLang.equalsIgnoreCase("zcn")) {
            toLang = "zh-CN";
        }
        else if (toLang.equalsIgnoreCase("zct")) {
            toLang = "zh-CT";
        }

        String jsonPayload = new StringBuilder()
                .append("{")
                .append("\"fromLang\":\"")
                .append(fromLang)
                .append("\",")
                .append("\"toLang\":\"")
                .append(toLang)
                .append("\",")
                .append("\"text\":\"")
                .append(textToTranslate)
                .append("\"")
                .append("}")
                .toString();

        URL url = new URL("http://api.whatsmate.net/v1/translation/translate");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-WM-CLIENT-ID", "FREE_TRIAL_ACCOUNT");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-WM-CLIENT-SECRET", "PUBLIC_SECRET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close stream.
        try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(jsonPayload.getBytes());
            os.flush();
        }

        int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        // System.out.println("Status Code: " + statusCode);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (statusCode == 200) ? conn.getInputStream() : conn.getErrorStream()
        ));

        String output;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
}
```